# Conversion of an Epsilon NFA to a DFA

Tags: automata, finite-state-machine

I need to convert this NFA to a DFA, but I only have the method for NFAs without Epsilons:

[image]

My calculation was:

[image]

But the expected result is:

[image]

Is there a process to use for converting this to get the above result?

Answer (score 3):

There is a method to convert Epsilon NFA to NFA by finding [Epsilon Closure](https://www.quora.com/What-is-epsilon-closure) for every state.Please, go through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSGcmaHNBFM) video. Thereafter, we can convert obtained NFA to DFA.I think this is the solution for the above question.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't create tuple states or the empty-set state in the example?

Comment: how would this get the empty set or {q1, q2, q3}?

Comment: Please retract your answer, it is incorrect

Comment: The link does not answer the question

Comment: Please check my answer now